# Repeater within Repeater (ajax based wepapp)

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, itemtemplate, nested-repeater

For the solution, I cannot use any postback methods, because this is all working through ajax. The solution need to be implemented in the asp.net code.

I have a `List<WebPage>` that contains a list of Links `(List<Link>)` and I need for all the links to bind repetitive information such as page title, id, url. Here is my current repeater.

```
<div id="result">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="results">
        <Itemtemplate>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" datasource='<%# Eval("Links") %>'>
                <Itemtemplate>
                    <tr class="gradeX odd">
                        <td><%# Eval("Id") %></td> //property of WebPage (part of results repeater)
                        <td><%# Eval("Title") %></td> //property of WebPage (part of results repeater)
                        <td><%# Eval("Url") %></td> //property of WebPage (part of results repeater)
                        <td><%# Eval("URL") %></td>//Property of Link
                        <td><%# Eval("URLType") %></td> //Property of Link
                        <td><%# Eval("URLState") %></td> //Property of Link
                    </tr>
                </Itemtemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
        </Itemtemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

of course this doesnt work, how can i do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can check this thread and check my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220715/creating-a-nested-repeater-control-dynamically/1220836#1220836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem,
>   "URL")

The key is to work your way back up to the parent repeater item, and then use the eval method.

Comment: Thanks man it worked! I'Ve been looking for a solution for this kind of problem for a while, and it was hidden in the databinder class =)

Answer (score 0):

Not of course actually.
I have almost the same, but into inner repeater datasource is set as `DataSource='<%# GetLinks(Container.DataItem) %>'`
where GetLinks returns casted enumerable of Links