# asp.net checkbox and nested repeaters

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, nested

I have nested repeaters and checkbox in each row(like a tree view or ctaegory and items view).
each check/uncheck the category should check/uncheck the items.
any suggestions?
Thanks,

Comment: Got some example code to help?

Comment: I think it would be best done in JS - f.ex. jQuery. Then on each checkbox change - you could just do the same with it's children..

Comment: Get an idea from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220715/creating-a-nested-repeater-control-dynamically/1220836#1220836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this before and I've done it with a simple JavaScript. Basically, when you bind you repeater, give the CategoryId to the checkbox's check event, e.g.

```
onchange="SelectCategory('<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>')"
```

have your child items wrapped around in a div with ID ending with CategoryId, e.g.

```
<div ID="divItems'<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>'">...</div>
```

this will allow you to find it in your SelectCategory(catId) function by doing

```
itemsDiv = document.GetElementById("divItems" + catId);
```

loop through its children and check your items:

```
var items = itemsDiv.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i].type.toUpperCase() == 'CHECKBOX')
            collection[i].checked = true; // or even "= CategoryCheckbox.checked"
    }
```

even better with jQuery:

```
$('#divItems' + catId).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: It should work fine with asp:CheckBox controls (server-side ones). The only thing to note is that client-side IDs of those controls may be different from what you expect. Do a View Source to see what I mean.

Comment: 10x for your help, I had to change it a bit but it worked very good!