# Generate datalist at runtime with fixed assigned templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-controls

I have to generate `DataLists` at runtime according to the items selected by the user.

How can this be done from the .aspx code-behind? I have a fixed `HeaderTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` format for each of the `DataList` that will be generated.

```
<HeaderTemplate>
<tr>Table Heading<tr>
<tr>    <th>ItemNo</th> <th>Item Detail</th><tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item1")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item2")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item3")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item4")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item5")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item6")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item7")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item8")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item9")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item10")%></td>    </tr>
<tr>    <td><%#CallFunc()%></td>    <td><%#Eval("Item11")%></td>    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

A small example of this kind of runtime datalist generation, and assigning these templates to it would be greatly helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can not you use gridview?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="Item ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="Item Name" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can I assign the templates to grid views as in the post above in the `code-behind`?

Comment: Can this be done in code-behind? Can you post a small example of this generation?

Comment: Screenshot I made for this thingg: http://i.imgur.com/t0elz.png Can you give some idea about how to do this?

Comment: @PraveenMenu: Can I keep a grid on the web page, and keep on adding data to in columns in some kind of above format? Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think I understand it fully. So the number of columns are dynamic?

Comment: @PraveenMenu: Yes, for each option checked by the user, a new column has to be generated. Or if you could any apporach to go for to use the above format i.e each column in the data control should have one queries result.

Comment: @PraveenMenu: I am just starting out with ASP.NET. An example would be of great help for this

Comment: try this friend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220715/creating-a-nested-repeater-control-dynamically

Comment: @PraveenMenu: How will this go into two columns then in case of a nested repeater?

Comment: Set RepeatColumns property of the repeater to 2 and the RepateDirection to Horizontal

Comment: @PraveenMenu: TRying now. But doesn't 2 limit the number of columns to 2 only? What if the user selects three options from checboxes?

Comment: @PraveenMenu: I don't think there is a RepeaterColumns property in the repater. Should I use DataList instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8410/discussion-between-cipher-and-praveenvenu)